# How to use ngIf according to a variable's value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

My code in `file.html` is

```
<button ion-button item-right>
        <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="save();"></ion-icon>
      </button>
```

`file.ts`

```
editmode = false;
```

What I want to achieve is if `editmode` is false then call `save()` function, and if editmode is true then call `editedu(elem,index)` function when button from html page is clicked.

Comment: Call a method saveOrEdit() from the click handler, and decide what to do based on the edit mode inside that method.

Comment: how do i write that ?

Comment: Seriously? `(click)="saveOrEdit()"` and in the component: `saveOrEdit() { if (this.editmode) { this.save(); } else { this.editedu(someEleme, someIndex); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juse use

```
<button ion-button item-right>
 <div *ngIf="editmode">     
<ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="editedu(elem,index);"></ion-icon>
</div>
 <div *ngIf="!editmode">     
<ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="save();"></ion-icon>
</div>
</button>
```

if you want to do it in single line,

```
<div   *ngIf=editmode ? save() : editedu(elem, index)">
   <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="save();"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: i am stuck at a point, can we chat for 2 minutes if you can take me out of this

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0e6oj6qwen8ifk/Screenshot%202017-09-03%2018.16.31.png?dl=0

Comment: I am trying to make a simple crud , i want to save new item, save an updated item  from 1 button....unable to do so

Comment: can you initiate a chat?

Comment: unable to see option till now

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary if (or you can call a method where you call another method depending on `editmode`)

```
(click)="editmode ? save() : editedu(elem, index)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the plunker demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/X5e6avkveGeVRqhzLVFr?p=preview

```
 //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)='editMode = !editMode'>Toggle editMode {{editMode}}</h2>
      <button (click)='editMode? save(): ""'>Call Me</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string
  editMode: boolean = true;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  save(): void {
    alert("Called because editMode is true");
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```